# Converting time intervals to HH:MI am/pm format using SQL

Tags: sql, time, oracle-sqldeveloper

My requirement is to convert 15 minute time intervals into HH:MI am/pm format using SQL. Giving an example:

```
IF interval = 0  => time = 12:00 am
IF interval = 15 => time = 12:15 am
IF interval = 30 => time = 12:30 am
IF interval = 45 => time = 12:45 am
IF interval = 60 => time = 01:00 am
```

and so on.,

So far, I've only managed to get the hourly intervals converted to HH:MI a/p format i.e. 12:00a, 01:00a etc., Here's a sample of the query that I'm using against my custom table.
`START_TIME` is the column containing the 15 minute interval entries.

```
select  START_TIME/15,
        case when (mod(START_TIME/15,4) = 0) then 
            case when (mod(START_TIME/15, 48) = 0) then (decode(START_TIME/15,0,'12:00 am',48,'12:00 pm'))
                                else (
                    case when (START_TIME/15 < 48) then (START_TIME/ 60 || 'am')
                        else (START_TIME / 60 - 12 || 'pm') 
                    end
                )
            end
                else '   ' 
end from MY_TABLE;
```

Can someone help me get it to work for all 15 min intervals? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try letting oracle do the time adding for you.

By default adding one to a date adds a single day.  You want to add the time in your start_time column.

We will start with a date with no time component using TRUNC.

```
SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE) FROM DUAL;
```

Then add 1/(60*24) * START_TIME minutes to this date and print out only the time portion of the date.

```
select TO_CHAR (TRUNC(SYSDATE) + (1/(60*24) * START_TIME), 'HH:MI AM')
from MY_TABLE
```

Comment: Thankyou! This suits my requirement perfectly! I just had to make one minor change to your query to use HH:MI AM instead of HH24:MI AM. We don't want 24 hour format and AM/PM to get mixed up. :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don't understand your problem. Oracle interval types already do this.

The purpose of intervals in Oracle are to store time offsets and to allow you to do what you seem to be asking. An interval can be added to a base date/timestamp to produce a new date/timestamp and formatted in any format use date/time formatting functions with TO_CHAR and TO_DATE.

```
create table intervals(base_time timestamp, offset_interval interval);

SQL> desc intervals
Name                                      Null?    Type
----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------

BASE_TIME                                          TIMESTAMP(6)
OFFSET_INTERVAL                                    INTERVAL DAY(2) TO SECOND(6)


SQL> insert into intervals values(sysdate, interval '15' minute);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into intervals values(sysdate, interval '30' minute);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into intervals values(sysdate, interval '45' minute);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into intervals values(sysdate, interval '60' minute);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into intervals values(sysdate, interval '90' minute);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into intervals values(sysdate, interval '120' minute);

1 row created.
```

And then add the base timestamp to the interval, and format with TO_CHAR()

```
SQL> select to_char(base_time + offset_interval, 'HH:MI AM') from intervals;

TO_CHAR(
--------
03:45 PM
04:00 PM
04:15 PM
04:30 PM
05:00 PM
05:30 PM

6 rows selected.
```